# Trying to get the sorter positon to retain after a table refresh

Tags: java, model, jtable, refresh, tablerowsorter

I have the following method:

```
private void passStingR(StringBuilder retVal) throws BadLocationException {

int scrollPositionR = scrollR.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();//get value of scroll position stores in javas memory

windowR.remove(scrollR);
tableR.getModel();
modelR.setRowCount(0);

Document docR = null;
try {
docR = loadXMLFromString(retVal.toString());//pull in the XML data into a new doc
} catch (Exception ex) {
Logger.getLogger(remit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

populate1R(docR);


tableR.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//prevent user from changing column order now at refresh level   

SimpleDateFormat time_formatterR = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String current_time_strR = time_formatterR.format(System.currentTimeMillis());

updatetFieldR.setText(current_time_strR);

scrollR.remove(tableR);
tableR = new JTable(modelR)
{
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
 if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                              String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 11);
                        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);

                    }

 }  



 return c;



};
};



TableColumn column = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        column = tableR.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
          if (i == 0) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(70); //sport column is bigger
          }
            if (i == 1) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(500); //sport column is bigger
             } 
                if (i == 7) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(30); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 8) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(20); //sport column is bigger
             }
                   if (i == 9) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(25); //sport column is bigger
             }
             if (i == 14) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(500); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 15) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(10); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 16) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(20); //sport column is bigger
             }

    }

 tableR.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//prevent the user from sorting the columns at intialise GUI stage even though the user cannnot change this      

 RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modelR);//creating a new sorter here from my modelR

tableR.setRowSorter(sorter);//set the sorter positon

scrollR = new JScrollPane(tableR);      
windowR.add(scrollR);

windowR.validate();

scrollR.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPositionR);


    }
```

I then create a sorter part way down the above code like below

```
RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modelR);//creating a new sorter here from my modelR

tableR.setRowSorter(sorter);//set the sorter positon
```

This allows me to sort on a particular column and order the column.
However the sorter than resets once a refresh takes place:
The refresh process is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Object source = e.getSource();

String stringfromDateR =  tffromDateR.getText();
String stringtoDateR =  tftoDateR.getText();

if(source == buttonR){
  if(timerR != null) {
      System.out.print("cancel");
      timerR.cancel();

    } 
//  System.out.print("cancel1bbbbb");
timerR = new Timer();    
//auto refresh begins
int delayR = 0; //0 seconds startup delay
int periodR = 7000; //x seconds between refreshes
timerR.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 


{    

public void run() {

try {
    getdataR(stringfromDateR,stringtoDateR);
 } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication63.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);           

}



      }
  }, delayR, periodR);    
} 

if(source == buttonR1){


 if(timerR != null) {
        timerR.cancel();
    }
modelR.setRowCount(0);
} 


    }
```

and then

```
private void getdataR(String stringfromDateR,String stringtoDateR) throws IOException, BadLocationException {

StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
URL oracle = new URL("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" );
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

String newLine = "\n";
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
retVal.append(inputLine).append(newLine);

}

in.close();

passStingR(retVal);

    }
```

How can i get the sorter to retain after the refresh has taken place. Im not sure if setting the

```
modelR.setRowCount(0);
```

causes the sorter to lose its sorter position.

I did experiment with get sortkeys but this didnt work, i also experimented with 
before the refresh happeened

```
RowSorter<? extends TableModel> tablesorterpos = tableR.getRowSorter();
```

and then applying

```
tableR.setRowSorter(tablesorterpos);
```

after the refresh but this didnt work

This is what i have tried

```
private void passStingR(StringBuilder retVal) throws BadLocationException {
 RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modelR);//creating a new sorter here from my modelR
List<? extends SortKey> sorterR = sorter.getSortKeys();
int scrollPositionR = scrollR.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();//get value of scroll position stores in javas memory

windowR.remove(scrollR);
tableR.getModel();
modelR.setRowCount(0);

Document docR = null;
try {
docR = loadXMLFromString(retVal.toString());//pull in the XML data into a new doc
} catch (Exception ex) {
Logger.getLogger(remit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

populate1R(docR);


tableR.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//prevent user from changing column order now at refresh level   

SimpleDateFormat time_formatterR = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String current_time_strR = time_formatterR.format(System.currentTimeMillis());

updatetFieldR.setText(current_time_strR);

scrollR.remove(tableR);
tableR = new JTable(modelR)
{
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
 if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                              String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 11);
                        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);

                    }

 }  



 return c;



};
};



TableColumn column = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        column = tableR.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
          if (i == 0) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(70); //sport column is bigger
          }
            if (i == 1) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(500); //sport column is bigger
             } 
                if (i == 7) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(30); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 8) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(20); //sport column is bigger
             }
                   if (i == 9) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(25); //sport column is bigger
             }
             if (i == 14) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(500); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 15) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(10); //sport column is bigger
             }
               if (i == 16) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(20); //sport column is bigger
             }

    }

 tableR.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//prevent the user from sorting the columns at intialise GUI stage even though the user cannnot change this      


sorter.setSortKeys(sorterR);
tableR.setRowSorter(sorter);//set the sorter positon


scrollR = new JScrollPane(tableR);      
windowR.add(scrollR);

windowR.validate();

scrollR.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPositionR);


    }
```

I get this error:

```
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsDeleted(DefaultRowSorter.java:880)
at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4276)
at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4120)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4397)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setNumRows(DefaultTableModel.java:321)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(DefaultTableModel.java:339)
at javaapplication63.remit.passStingR(remit.java:238)
at javaapplication63.remit.getdataR(remit.java:227)
at javaapplication63.remit.access$000(remit.java:60)
    at javaapplication63.remit$1.run(remit.java:187)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current sort keys from  the `DefaultRowSorter`. So the basic logic would be:

1. getSortKeys()
2. refresh TableModel
3. setSortKeys(...)

Edit:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableSortSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Sport",
                                    "# of Years",
                                    "Vegetarian"};

    private Object[][] data =
    {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    private JTable table;


    public TableSortSSCCE()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize( table.getPreferredSize() );
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear Table");
        clear.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
            }
        });
        add(clear, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JButton reload = new JButton("Reload Table");
        reload.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                TableRowSorter sorter = (TableRowSorter)table.getRowSorter();
                List<? extends RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = sorter.getSortKeys();

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
                table.setModel(model);
                table.setAutoCreateRowSorter( true );

                sorter = (TableRowSorter)table.getRowSorter();
                sorter.setSortKeys( sortKeys );
            }
        });
        add(reload, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableSortSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableSortSSCCE newContentPane = new TableSortSSCCE();
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this - i will put in my main question what i have tried and the error output i get

Comment: @MrAssistance, works fine for me. See edit. I just modified the code from the Swing tutorial on `Sorting and Filtering`. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you need more help. Again we are not interested in your application or data, only minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i still cant get it to retain - the issue arises here  List<? extends RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = sorter.getSortKeys(); where it acts as if Someone killed this Thread, behave as if Timer cancelled

Comment: I imported both import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;

Comment: okay i have a made a little bit of progress I placed this tableR.setAutoCreateRowSorter( true ); before the sortkeys are set which has meant that i no longer get that error. However the sort still doesnt retain..

Comment: after playing around a bit placing the setsortkeys lower down in the code i manage to get it to retain, many thanks for your help ...it was a little frustrating finding the right place to put the lines of code

Comment: i placed it after the validate

Comment: @MrAssistance, `it was a little frustrating finding the right place to put the lines of code` - sorry I don't understand the problem. The example is simple and straight forward which is the way you need to look at your code. That is, you simply save the keys as the first step to your process, then restore them as the last step. What you do in the middle should not matter. That was what my code demonstrated. This is why you create a simple example to learn the concept. You ignore the design of your current code. Once it is working you then redesign your code when you understand the concept.

Comment: `i placed it after the validate` - again, I don't understand that comment. My code does not use a validate(). There is no need for a validate. I should you two methods for updating the data in a table. That is you update the model. There is no need to play with the table or scrollpane or any other component. Again, it looks like your logic is too complex for the problem.

Comment: hi yes its hard to put down all the details as the program is quite large and it contains some sensitive material - always a little tricky to display everything nevertheless your suggestions and example led me to fix the issue. Many thanks